# Apache2 with PHP-fpm and symbolic link strange behaviour

Tags: php, apache, symlink

I tried to "centralize" some php files contained in some directories by linking them (ln -s) in the document route of some virtual hosts.
To explain myself, in the document root of a virtual host (VH) I have "project -> ../centraldir/project."
In project I have an edit.php file that with jquery recalls a pdf.php file that is used to make a pdf document.

```
$('#pdf').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = "/pdf.php?numero=<?php echo $id?>&tipo=preventivo";
  $('#close').trigger('click');
});
```

This file (pdf.php) is both present in the document root of the VH and in the centraldir directory, with different functions even if with the same purpose.

The problem is that only the one contained in centraldir is recalled, if I delete it instead the one in the VH document root is used. I would like this to be used when the file is present in the vistrual host.

Thank you all

**Update:**
The documnet root of VH crm.mysite.it/ and the directory centraldir/ are in the some directory /www.

This is the result of ls -al executed in the VH document root

```
-rw-r--r--  1 stone users     7883 14 gen 17.22 pdf.php
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root        17 25 ott 18.27 project-> ../centraldir/project/phone
```

and this is the ls -al executed in the centraldir.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 adminuser users  4096 13 gen 21.07 project
-rw-r--r--  1 adminuser users  5895 24 ott 09.48 pdf.php
```

The virtual host configuration file

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.6:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.it
        ServerName crm.mysite.it

        DocumentRoot /www/crm.mysite.it/
        AccessFileName .htaccess
        <Directory /www/crm.mysite.it/>
          Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

And this it .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^crm.mysite.it$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* . [F,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$   $1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$   $1.php [L]
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a diagram of the directory structure - I'm struggling to picture where the files and symlinks fit together. It might be useful to also include a minimal version of the Apache VirtualHost configuration, and show how it relates. Particularly relevant would be any RewriteRule or Alias lines that are in use.

Comment: Thanks for your interest